# How to detect event when user click on selected segment Control in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uisegmentedcontrol

I am using `UISegmentControl` in swift now I have created `@IBAction` so the type is `ValueChanged` but when I click on selected segment `@IBAction` does not invokes. so I tried with`touchUpInside`, `.allEvents` but didNot works.

Comment: that's because you need: .valueChanged instead of .touchUpInside

Answer (score -1):

Please try this.

1. Create @IBIoutlet.

   ```
   @IBOutlet var segControl: UISegmentedControl!
   ```
2. Initialize Value change event.

   ```
   segControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(onChanged(_:)), for: .valueChanged)
   ```
3. Handle change event.

   ```
     @objc func onChanged(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {
        if segControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 {
          print("First Segment")
        } else if segControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 1 {
          print("Second Segment")
        } else if segControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 2 {
          print("Third Segment")
        }
   }
   ```

**OR Using @IBAction**

```
@IBAction func onsegControl_Click(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {
   if sender.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 {
     print("First Segment")
   }
   else { 
     print("Second Segment")
   }
}
```